# Pure CSS Horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create the look and feel of tabs that you can switch between for a small web application I am making. You can create new tabs that will show new content. The tabs will continue to grow in number horizontally the more there are, to the point of the browsers width. After the tabs are filling up full width, I want the ability to scroll horizontally to see the overflow of tabs. My issue is with the code I have tried, it makes the width of the tabs smaller on overflow and does not allow scrolling. How can I achieve the desired effect?

Here is my code:

```js
let $tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
let $lastTab = $tabs[$tabs.length - 1];



$tabs.forEach((tab) => {
  
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const $currentlyActive = document.querySelector('.active');
    
    $currentlyActive.classList.remove('active');

    tab.classList.add('active');

    let newTab = document.createElement('div');
    newTab.className = 'tab';
    newTab.innerText = 'Day ??';
    $lastTab.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', newTab);
    $tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  });
});
```

```css
.breakout-holder {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heading {
  /* background-color: grey; */
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.heading::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.tab.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, lightgreen 50%, lightgrey 50%) right;
  background-size: 200%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
  z-index: 5000;
}

.tab {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: black;
  height: 90%;
  width: 10ch;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black; */
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* tab.active */

  background-color: lightgrey !important;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.tab:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.tab::before,
.tab::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  box-shadow: -3px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transform: skew(-5deg, -10deg);
  width: 1px;
  height: 60%;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: none;
}

.tab::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 1px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transform: skew(5deg, 10deg);
}

.tab::before,
.tab::after {
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
}

.tab.active:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tab.active:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="breakoutStyle.css">
    <title>Breakout room form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="breakout-holder">
        <div class="heading">
            <div class="tab active">
                Day 1
            </div>
            <div class="tab">
                Day 2
            </div>
            <div class="tab">
                Day 3
            </div>
            <div class="tab">
                Day 4
            </div>
            <div class="tab">
                Day 5
            </div>
            <div class="tab">
                Day 6
            </div>
            <div class="tab">
                Day 7
            </div>
            <div class="tab">
                Day 8
            </div>
            <div class="tab">
                Day 9
            </div>
            <div class="tab">
                Day 10
            </div>
            <div class="tab" >
                +
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: When I use the snippet, the tabs stay the same width and there is horizontal scroll.

Comment: Why did you add `.heading::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}`?